# Jabber/XMPP protocol in pure Clojure

Tags: clojure, xmpp

I'm looking for Jabber/XMPP protocol implementation in pure Clojure.

I'm find [xmpp-clj](https://github.com/zkim/xmpp-clj) but it a wrapper around the smack jabber/XMPP library.

Comment: One of the main benefits of Clojure is that you have access to the huge pre-existing library of Java / other JVM code that already exists. What difference does it make if it's in pure Clojure?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know the whole of the net, though I'm comfortable saying there is no mature or widely used XMPP library written entirely in Clojure as of May 2013.

I wouldn't mind such a library if you are volunteering or course ;)